# After adding relation instrumentedlist causes query-invoked flush on sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have defined sqlalchemy models like that:

```
class Item(base.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'list_item'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode)

    list_id = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('list.id'), nullable=False)

    # container holding images grouped by type
    image_container = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(
        'ImageContainer', backref="item", cascade="all, delete-orphan")


class List(base.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'list'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.Unicode(255), nullable=False, unique=True)

    # relationships
    items = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(
        'Item', cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref='list')


class BaseImageContainer(object):
    container_type = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(128))

    @sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr
    def image(cls):  # pylint: disable=no-self-argument
        return sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(
            'Image', uselist=False, backref='items')

    @sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr
    def image_id(cls):  # pylint: disable=no-self-argument
        return sqlalchemy.Column(
            sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('image.id'),
            primary_key=True)

    sqlalchemy.UniqueConstraint(
        'obj_id', 'container_type', name='one_image_per_container_type')


class ImageContainer(base.Base, BaseImageContainer):
    __tablename__ = 'image_container_item'

    obj_id = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('list_item.id'),
        primary_key=True)


class Image(base.Base):
    '''Represents an Image at a high level (title, credits, description)'''
    __tablename__ = 'image'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode)
    description = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode)
```

I am adding images to the container using code like that:

```
for container_name, image in images:
   container = ImageContainer()
   container.container_type = container_name
   container.image = image

   item.image_container.append(container)
```

Append at the last line causes for query-invoked autoflush (and because we are in the middle of building list and item object it ends up horribly with fatal error as list_id cannot be null).

But if last line is replaced with this:

```
   container.item = item
```

It's all green.

I have exactly the same problem with List and Item.

```
List.items.append(Item)
```

causes Query-invoked autoflush, but

```
Item.list = List
```

is all good again.

Does it mean that we should not use append on InstrumentedList when building complex models?